# python: returning results or taking output variable as argument

Tags: python

I have a python function that takes has the following signature.

```
def myfunc(x, y, result=None):

   # At some moment, I do something like:
   result = some_operation(x, y)
   return result
```

When I call the function, I have to do:

```
r = myfunc(x, y, r)
```

However, is it possible to do something like:

```
myfunc(x, y, r)
```

rather than relying on the caller to assign the value back to the output variable. I should mention that r is a complex object with a data field which is the one that gets changed in the function.

Comment: Don't you thin that this will reduce your further understaning of the code? Every time that you call the function you would have to remember that it changes that variable implicitly...

Comment: That is a bad design, confusing. Function that mutate their arguments should only used when it may hurt heavily performance. Even then it is better to write function, one that modifies data structure in-place, and other that does not mutate any argument.

Comment: First of all you need to be sure that the argument can be mutated in-place and that there won't be any issues with that. If the variable can be mutated in place you can do it. But in practice I'd concur to what m.wasowski said.

Comment: My issue is that this is performance related. The data object is an 3-D array of size 512x512x512. I would like to reuse it unless it is for really small objects.